# Pass None to DRF SerializerField's to_representation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following SerializerField:

```
class TimestampField(Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return ''

        return value.timestamp()
```

And I use it like this in my serializer:

```
class ArticlePhotobookSerializer(ModelSerializer):  
    delivery_date_from = TimestampField()
    delivery_date_to = TimestampField()
```

Now the getter `delivery_date_to` can return None, which I want to transform into an empty string using the `to_representation` method. however, when I use the Serializer to parse this None value, it doesn't even enter the `to_representation` method and immediately returns `None`. What should I change to also use the method `to_representation` for `None`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default serializer's `to_representation` method skip fields with None value (see [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L414)).

You can write mixin class to override default `to_representation`:

```
class ToReprMixin(object):  
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = OrderedDict()
        fields = [field for field in self.fields.values() if not field.write_only]

        for field in fields:
            try:
                attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
            except SkipField:
                continue

            ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

        return ret
```

and use it in your serializers:

```
class ArticlePhotobookSerializer(ToReprMixin, ModelSerializer):  
    ...
```

Comment: That's a nice "feature"... ;-) Thanks for pointing this out to me! I was hoping that one setting would do, this is quite a big change for such a small thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the result of `to_representation` when there is no instance (not exactly the same problem as you had, but matches the question title), `to_representation` will not even be called in DRF v3. One can change the result by subclassing the [`get_initial`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/2510456817d9d2840a4080e69a0efb8a4da423ac/rest_framework/serializers.py#L392) method:

```
    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Return a value to use when the field is being returned as a primitive
        value, without any object instance.
        """
        if callable(self.initial):
            return self.initial()
        return self.initial
```

Heres an example:

```
    def get_initial(self) -> dict:
        return {'display_name': 'moocows'}
```

Here we use the context as initial representation:

```
    def get_initial(self) -> dict:
        return self.context
```